# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol. Creating Binary Tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, compiler-errors, binary-tree, lnk2019

I created Linked list and it has no problem and runs. Plus i have to include Binary Tree. and its giving me this error

`1>  Generating Code...
1>  Skipping... (no relevant changes detected)
1>  main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall SDI::BinaryTree::insert(int)" (?insert@BinaryTree@SDI@@QAEHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall SDI::BinaryTree::preOrder(void)" (?preOrder@BinaryTree@SDI@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\Muugii\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\LinkedList\Debug\LinkedList.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

BinaryTree.h

> ## ifndef SDI_BINARYTREE
>
> ## define SDI_BINARYTREE

## include

```
namespace SDI
{
    class BinaryTree
    {
        class BTNode
        {
        public:
            int data;
            BTNode *left;
            BTNode *right;
        };

    public:
        BinaryTree();
        ~BinaryTree();

        int insert(const int value);
        int preOrder() const;
        int clearTree();

    private:

        BTNode *headPtr;

        int insert(const int value, BTNode *leaf);
        int clearTree(BTNode *leaf) const;
        int preOrder(BTNode *leaf) const;

    };
};

#endif
```

BinaryTree.cpp

```
#include"BinaryTree.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


SDI::BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
    headPtr = nullptr;
}

SDI::BinaryTree::~BinaryTree()
{
    //clearTree(headPtr);
}

int SDI::BinaryTree::insert(const int value, BTNode *leaf)
{
    if (value < leaf->data)
    {
        if (leaf->left != nullptr)
        {
            insert(value, leaf->left);
        }
        else
        {
            leaf->left = new BTNode;
            leaf->left->data = value;
            leaf->left->left = nullptr;
            leaf->left->right = nullptr;
        }
    }
    else if (value >= leaf->data)
    {
        if (leaf->right != nullptr)
        {
            insert(value, leaf->right);
        }
        else
        {
            leaf->right = new BTNode;
            leaf->right->data = value;
            leaf->right->left = nullptr;
            leaf->right->right = nullptr;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Linkedlist.h"
#include "BinaryTree.h"

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    SDI::LinkedList myList;
    //SDI::BinaryTree myTree;
    int inp;

....

if (inp2 == 'a')
                {
                    int num;

                        cout << "\nPlease enter a value to add: ";
                        cin >> num;
                        myTree.insert(num);
                        cout << "\n\t\tValue has been successfully saved\n\n\n";


                }
```

I have tried looking up online, couldn't find any. It would be great help.

Comment: What prevented you from fixing your formatting before posting?

Comment: Well, it tells you right there, "public: int __thiscall SDI::BinaryTree::preOrder(void)".  You have no implementation for that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you have two functions with name insert. And the first one

```
int insert(const int value);
```

was only declared but not defined.

Comment: Thank you thank you, i am sorry everyone, i just started coding. Please dont be that rude.

Comment: As @Dietmar Kühl said you need to define also function preOrder

Answer (score 0):

Which part of the error message is unclear to you? It clearly states that you haven't implemented two of your methods:

```
int SDI::BinaryTree::insert(const int value) {
    return 0; // the implementation probably needs some patching up
}
int SDI::BinaryTree::preOrder() const {
    return 0; // as does this one
}
```